# CSV data to array and then resave as CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, file-storage

I have a CSV file that I convert to an array using this

```
public function getCsvAsArray($filePath, $keyField = null)
{
    $rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filePath));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $formattedData = [];

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $formattedData[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }

    return $formattedData;
}
```

I then do some processing off that array, and by the end of it, my data takes the following structure

```
0 => array:3 [
    "ID" => "10338"
    "Date" => "19/08/2011"
    "Value" => "30"
]
```

So it contains the Header name as the key, and then the value.

What I am trying to do now is convert this back to the CSV file.  At the moment, I am trying

```
$fp = fopen($this->storagePath, "a+");
foreach ($this->csvData  as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

But this does nothing to the original CSV file, and I dont seem to get any errors.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _But this does nothing to the original CSV file_ Is whatever you pass as `$filepath` the same as `$this->storagePath` ???

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Do you want to replace the file or add this new stuff to it?

Comment: Can you verify that `$this->csvData` is not empty array?

Comment: Yes, I need to replace the file.   And csvData is not empty

Comment: _From Manual_ **'a+'** Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not just adding to the end of the original file, did you check all the way to the end of the file?

Comment: If you want to **replace** the file you should use `w+` flag. read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Also, depends on the server, php doesn't throw errors to screen sometimes, you should check server log file, maybe the file isn't writable, or you don't have permission to write to that file.